# Add file name and empty column to existing file in awk

Tags: bash, awk, header

Dear all I would like to add to my existing file "file name" and "empty column" including their header in one awk step:

input:

```
head1 head2 head3
value1 value2 value3
```

Ouptut:

```
filename note head1 head2 head3
file1 empty_column value1 value2 value3
```

So I just add to header "Filename" and "Note". Under the Filename is the name of my file and under the note is empty field.

I can do this with two awk commands and paste it together, but is there way to do it in one-liner?

My idea was:

```
awk -v OFS="\t" '{print FILENAME, $2="",$3 - end}' infile
```

But do not know how to add header and how to print moved fields (form position  $1 to $3).

Note: I have about 77 columns - not only three like in example.

Thank you for any ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

give this a try:

```
awk '{$0=FILENAME "\t" (NR==1?"note":"") "\t" $0}7' file
```

#### Update based on the comment:

```
awk '{$0=(NR==1? "NAME\tnote":FILENAME"\t") "\t" $0}7' file
```

Output:

```
NAME    note    head1 head2 head3
file            value1 value2 value3
```

Comment: Thank you Kent, it looks that works only what I do need is name of the first column (right now it is the same like FILENAME). And could you please explain more your syntax? Thank you again!

Comment: It is possible maybe skip column note and just add FILENAME with header NAME?

Comment: @Geroge I don't understand what do you mean...  which part do you have problem to understand? the code is pretty straightforward.

Comment: the part with "note" works good. But FILENAME prints me name of file (what I want), but I need in first row "NAME" and under this my file name. I hope it is clear - example above explains everything. Thank you.