# add filename without the extension at certain columns using awk

Tags: awk, header, text-processing

I would like to leave empty first four columns, then I want to add filename without extension in the last 4 columns. I have files as file.frq and goes on. Later I will apply this to the 200 files in loop.

**input**

```
CHR     POS            REF     ALT     AF      HOM     Het     Number of animals
1       94980034        C       T       0       0       0       5
1       94980057        C       T       0       0       0       5
```

**Desired output**

```
                                      file     file    file    file
CHR     POS            REF     ALT     AF      HOM     Het     Number of animals
1       94980034        C       T       0       0       0       5
1       94980057        C       T       0       0       0       5
```

I tried this from [Add file name and empty column to existing file in awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39096717/add-file-name-and-empty-column-to-existing-file-in-awk)

```
awk '{$0=(NR==1? " \t"" \t"" \t"" \t":FILENAME"\t") "\t" $0}7' file2.frq
```

But it gave me this:

```
                                        CHR     POS     REF     ALT     AF      HOM     Het     Number of animals
file2.frq               1       94980034        C       T       0       0       0       5
file2.frq               1       94980057        C       T       0       0       0       5
file2.frq               1       94980062        G       C       0       0       0       5
```

and I also tried this

```
awk -v OFS="\t" '{print FILENAME, $1=" ",$2=" ",$3=" ", $4=" ",$5 - end}' file2.frq
```

but it gave me this

```
                                        CHR     POS     REF     ALT     AF      HOM     Het     Number of animals
file2.frq               1       94980034        C       T       0       0       0       5
file2.frq               1       94980057        C       T       0       0       0       5
```

any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your input is tab-separated like your desired output:

```
awk '
    BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }
    NR==1 {
        orig = $0
        fname = FILENAME
        sub(/\.[^.]*$/,"",fname)
        $1=$2=$3=$4 = ""
        $5=$6=$7=$8 = fname
        print
        $0 = orig
    }
1' file.txt
                                file    file    file    file
CHR     POS     REF     ALT     AF      HOM     Het     Number of animals
1       94980034        C       T       0       0       0       5
1       94980057        C       T       0       0       0       5
```

To see it in table format:

```
$ awk '
    BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }
    NR==1 {
        orig = $0
        fname = FILENAME
        sub(/\.[^.]*$/,"",fname)
        $1=$2=$3=$4 = ""
        $5=$6=$7=$8 = fname
        print
        $0 = orig
    }
1' file.txt | column -s$'\t' -t
                         file  file  file  file
CHR  POS       REF  ALT  AF    HOM   Het   Number of animals
1    94980034  C    T    0     0     0     5
1    94980057  C    T    0     0     0     5
```

Comment: Woow! Such an elegant solution! Many thanks!